# posting to app page

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have an app fb page and would like to be able to post messages on it.  I am currently able to get my android code to post a msg to my own wall but I want to be able to post to my app page also.

1. Is this possible?
2. Do you have to be a member of the page also?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#feed) it says:

> **feed**
>
> This connection corresponds to the Page's Wall. You can create a link,
>   post or status message by issuing an HTTP POST request to the
>   PAGE_ID/feed connection. To see more details please see links, posts,
>   and status messages documentation.

This official blog post (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465/) shows how to do so with php, and a normal post request using curl, you can use that to create a java code for android.

Comment: Is this inferring you must be a member of that page then?

Comment: Some pages let all user post on their wall, some require the users to like the page before they have that ability.
That can be set in the page settings. The Documentation notes that "Publishing to a Page also requires the publish_stream permission, unless otherwise noted" and so if your application needs to post to a page, it needs to get the permission along with a valid access token.